# creating for loops using R, where each row form a dataframe does to different datafames

Tags: r, loops

Hi I am trying to create a loop where each row from a dataframe goes a specific location in different dataframes. I have been stuck doing this for days and I would appreciate any help!

Here is my "list_files" dataframe

```
0.364618
0.944114
0.274912
0.600096
1.718930
1.071100
1.733920
0.349970
0.885879
0.254805
0.592313
1.539530
0.913408
1.741790
0.311971
0.877417
0.244049
0.541382
1.469480
0.926704
1.622540
0.317075
0.917018
0.233637
0.548263
1.513830
0.959897
1.611970
```

Target dataframe:

df_fa

df_md

df_awf

df_daxon

df_de_axial

df_de_radial

df_de_tort

Manually, I am trying to each row from list_files to go to a specific location in each of those dataframes above

#### e.g. copy rows 1:7 from list_files to [2,1] for every dataframe

```
df_fa[2,1]<-list_file[1,]      
df_md[2,1]<-list_file[2,]      
df_awf[2,1]<-list_file[3,]      
df_daxon[2,1]<-list_file[4,]      
df_de_axial[2,1]<-list_file[5,]      
df_de_radial[2,1]<-list_file[6,]     
df_de_tort[2,1]<-list_file[7,]
```

e.g. copy rows 8:14 from list_files to [2,2] for every dataframe

```
df_fa[2,2]<-list_file[8,]
df_md[2,2]<-list_file[9,]
df_awf[2,2]<-list_file[10,]
df_daxon[2,2]<-list_file[11,]
df_de_axial[2,2]<-list_file[12,]
df_de_radial[2,2]<-list_file[13,]
df_de_tort[2,2]<-list_file[14,]
```

e.g. copy rows 15:21 from list_files to [2,3] for every dataframe .

```
df_fa[2,3]<-list_file[15,]
df_md[2,3]<-list_file[16,]
df_awf[2,3]<-list_file[17,]
df_daxon[2,3]<-list_file[18,]
df_de_axial[2,3]<-list_file[19,]
df_de_radial[2,3]<-list_file[20,]
df_de_tort[2,3]<-list_file[21,]
```

e.g. copy rows 22:28 from list_files to [2,4] for every dataframe

```
df_fa[2,4]\<-list_file[22,]
df_md[2,4]<-list_file[23,]
df_awf[2,4]<-list_file[24,]
df_daxon[2,4]<-list_file[25,]
df_de_axial[2,4]<-list_file[26,]
df_de_radial[2,4]<-list_file[27,]
df_de_tort[2,4]<-list_file[28,]
```

I have manually tried to code, but that would be very labor intensive if I want to repeat the process to several dataframes

Comment: To confirm, each of your target dfs already has one row, and your want to add these values to a second row? Do your target dataframes already have the requisite number of columns? What is your larger goal in making these dataframes?

Comment: Each of my target dfs have 64 empty rows and 8 columns. For this specific example, I want to add the first 7 values to the second row, first column of every dataframe,  the next 7 values to the second row, second column of every data frame; the next 7 values to the second row, third column of every data frame, etc....  Until I go though all the 28 values in the  list_files dataframe. My larger goal is to create  7 different dataframes that contains participant value for every row

Comment: Right but why? So is `list_files` data from one participant that you want to put in these different dataframes, and you'd then be repeating this process for each participant? I'm just wondering if there's an [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/) here.

Comment: yes! list_files is data from one participants only.  I have 64 participants in total.  To be honest, I don't know how to create a loop that goes to every subject folder, accesses 2 subfolders, and download all csv files. There are 8 .csv files per participant and every row within each file corresponds to a value in one of the 7 dataframes. Hopefully this is helpful

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple solutions depending on your problem.
Here one that i feel intuitive:

As you must decompose a column into four consecutive columns, you can conform a matrix this way:

```
m <- matrix(list_file[1:28, 1, drop = TRUE], nrow = 7, ncol = 4)
```

then assign that matrix as columns:

```
df_fa[2,1:4] <- m[1,, drop=F]
df_md[2,1:4] <- m[2,, drop=F]
df_awf[2,1:4] <- m[3,, drop=F]
df_daxon[2,1:4] <- m[4,, drop=F]
df_de_axial[2,1:4] <- m[5,, drop=F]
df_de_radial[2,1:4] <- m[6,, drop=F]
df_de_tort[2,1:4] <- m[7,, drop=F]
```

Comment: for  df_fa[2,1:4] <- m[1,, drop=F]. I am seeing that it copying the first from the matrix instead of the first column